# Order Code Snippets in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, code-snippets

I am using code snippets in Xcode often but most of my snippets end up in the bottom of the pane in snippets library . Is there anyway we can order the snippets as we like , so we can drag and drop faster.

Comment: @Bhavesh Nai: please use `code markdown` only for code.

Comment: You could start typing the name of the snippet in code and let autocompletion do the search for you.

Comment: I rather type the code my self than going to the panel then search for the snippet and drag and dropping it. Does not save much time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't found a way to do it. My work around has been to prefix the snippet titles with my initials (SV_) and filter using the filter box. This does not allow you to sort your snippets but at least gets rid of the snippets that are not yours!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess I have to settle for this. Annoying thing is I am using few exiting snippets as well so I have to scroll up and down often or search for them. I guess I have to duplicate them and order them as you suggest.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable expectation, so please file a bug report (enhancement request) with Apple!

Comment: Filed it , Thanks for the suggestion. Can't believe they missed something like this since code snippets have been a feature for a really long time.